# what way to multiply a NSString price by the quantity? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

Hello i have a price of a product which is a NSString for ex. is @"35.45";

How can i take that and multiply it by `double value = [sender value];`

which is the counter for my UIStepper;

Comment: Convert String price to double/float , multiply it with quantity, and convert it again back to string to show it on a label!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `doubleValue` method of `NSString`

```
NSString *priceString = @"35.45";
double priceValue = [priceString doubleValue];
double quantityValue = [sender value];
double result = priceValue * quantityValue;
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", result];
```

Comment: Why are you using floatValue and store it into a double? That's completely pointless. You introduced a very significant rounding error by using floatValue instead of doubleValue; doing double arithmetic isn't going to fix that.

Comment: A "very significant rounding error" by converting a 2 digits number like 35.45 into a float ?! You think ? For the sake of pedantic correctness I edited my answer, but this is not going to change anything.

Comment: so thanks for the math part of it, once i pass it to a next view controller, and i go back and not change the value of the quantity so its 1, it doesnt change to the initial value if before hand i put it times 3.

Comment: I don't really understand what you say, can you update your question with the code that you tried ?

Comment: so basically if i pass over at a quantity of 5, and later on, leave it at quantity 1, it still remembers its at quantity 5

Comment: Still don't understand what your app does sorry... Show me the code or give me a more detailed explanation of what you app does (or should do)